# Can one alias multiple font names with a single name in CSS?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I know that it's possible to alias a single font name easily with `@font-face`, especially if it's a custom font rather than a builtin one like Arial. However, is it possible to alias many font names with a single name? For example, if I have

```
font-family: 'Font A', 'Font B', 'Font C', ..., sans-serif;
```

Can I use a single name to refer to all of those fonts so I can write

```
font-family: name;
```

instead?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this with a CSS property.

```
:root {
  --font: 'Font A', 'Font B', 'Font C', sans-serif;
}

.fancyFont {
  font-family: var(--font);
}
```

Comment: Why the double dashes next to `font`? Can you explain what `var()` does?

Comment: @JamesKo The dashes essentially define an entity as a variable, which can be referenced anywhere in your stylesheet using var(). You can read more about it here: [Modzilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do this with raw CSS. You should try implementing a CSS preprocessor, like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/guide) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). I know for sure it's possible to do this with SASS, a golden example is right there in the link.

```
$font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
$primary-color: #333;

body {
    font: 100% $font-stack;
    color: $primary-color;
}
```

You would just list all of the fonts you want to use for the `font` or the `font-family` property, and assign that "stack" to a variable with **`$`** and **`:`**. Then you can refer to the whole list of fonts, just by using the variable.